How to Solve the Integral of $\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ between $0$ and $\sqrt{k}$, for positive integer $k$
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{k}} \lfloor x^2 \rfloor \, dx$$
where $k$ is a positive integer
If $k$ is a square number it's clear that the answer would be the sum of squares up to $(k-1)^2$, however, I'm struggling to find a solution when $k$ isn't a perfect square. I've looked into converting the integral into this expression:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} n \cdot \int_{\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n+1}} dx$$
but I'm not sure it's correct.

Well, if it isn't a square then you can still do the integral up to $\lfloor \sqrt k \rfloor$ your way and the integrand is constant on the stub interval at the end.

Your conversion is correct, and each integral then is just $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n$.  A lot of cancelling happens, and the answer involves the sum of square-roots, not squares.

"f k is a square number it's clear that the answer would be the sum of squares up to (k-1)^2" Are you sure?  If $k=3$ we have $[x^2]=0$ for $0\le x < 1$ and $=1$ for $1\le x < \sqrt 2$ and $=2$ for $\sqrt 2\le x < \sqrt 3$ and $=3$ for $\sqrt 2\le x <3$.  So $\int_0^3[x^2]dx = (\sqrt 2-1) + 2(\sqrt 3- \sqrt 2)+ 3(3-\sqrt3)=9-\sqrt3-\sqrt 2-1$.

But we can get a pattern that can telescope nicely.  $\sum_{j=0}^k i(\sqrt{j+1}-\sqrt j)$.

Oops I made an err.  $[x^2]=3$ for $\sqrt 3\le x=2$ and $[x^2]=4$ for $2< x< \sqrt 5$ and so on.  So $\int_0^3[x^2]dx = (\sqrt 2-1) + 2(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2) + 3(\sqrt 4-\sqrt 3) + 4(\sqrt 5-\sqrt 4)+5(\sqrt 6-\sqrt 5) + 6(\sqrt 7 -\sqrt 6)+ 7(\sqrt 8-\sqrt 7)+8(\sqrt 9 - \sqrt 8) = 8\sqrt 9 - \sqrt 8-\sqrt 7 -\sqrt 6-\sqrt 6-\sqrt 5-\sqrt 4-\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2-\sqrt 1$.  So for $k = m^2$ we get $\int = (m-1)k -\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\sqrt j$.  We can figure the for $\sqrt k$ not being an integer by a fractional part of a product.

So if $\sqrt{m} \le x < \sqrt{m+1}$ then $\lfloor x^2\rfloor = m$ and $\int_{\sqrt{m}}^{\sqrt{m+1}} \lfloor x^2\rfloor dx = \int_{\sqrt{m}}^{\sqrt{m+1}} m\ dx= m(\sqrt{m+1} - \sqrt m)$
So.....
$\int_0^{\sqrt k} \lfloor x^2\rfloor dx=$
$\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\int_{\sqrt{m}}^{\sqrt{m+1}} \lfloor x^2\rfloor dx =\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} m(\sqrt{m+1} - \sqrt m)$
And by telescoping
that equals $(k-1)\sqrt{k} -\sum_{m=0}^{k-1} \sqrt{m}$

The issue that $k$ not being a perfect square was throwing me as it was no longer a concern  (we are "stepping" from $\sqrt m$ to $\sqrt{m+1}$ which is a whole indexed step) so the indexing is still on whole integers.  I overlooked the possibility that $k$ might not be an integer and if $m < k < m+1$ we'd "step" for $\sqrt m$ to $\sqrt k$ which isn't an "integer step".  Ooops..... but then on the third hand, the question actually stipulates that $k \in \mathbb N$..... You posted your answer 2 minutes before I did.  But they are both the same.  Should I delete mine?

I did actually make the error the op did and took a long time for me to muddle through the mistake.  You cut through it right away.
